# How to check which arguments are being passed to a mockup callback function in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have a simple React component, which receive a property `type` and a callback `onClick`.
When user click the component callback is execute passing property `type`.

I need to write a test using jest and enzyme for it.
I am using the following code with a mock callback but I am not able to see the argumetns passed in by the component.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
   const Component = ({type, onClick}) => <div onClick={() => onClick(type)}></div>


describe('<Component />', () => {
  it('should call callback on click getting passed value', () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component type="xxx" onClick={mockCallback} />)
    wrapper.simulate('click')
    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalled() // this is ok
    expect(mockCallback).toBeCalledWith("xxx")// ISSUE HERE: always false
  })
})
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the problem or just a typo, but your component definition is missing curly braces: `const Component = ({ type, onClick }) => <div onClick={() => onClick(type)}></div>` (also it's _const_, not _cont_)

Comment: With that change, I've tried running your code, it works just fine, all tests pass

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the props correctly.

React function components take only one param and it is `props`.

change this

```
const Component = (type, onClick) => <div onClick={() => onClick(type)}></div>
```

to

```
const Component = (props) => <div onClick={() => props.onClick(props.type)}></div>

// or destructure the props within the brackets

const Component = ({type, onClick}) => <div onClick={() => onClick(type)}></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have my problem with jest

Comment: @Radex like I said, I've tried running your code, it works just finde. The problem must be somewhere else